# avr-gcc version: won't update from 5.4 to 9.2

Tags: gcc, cmake, avr-gcc, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run compile some arduino code in my linux terminal and keep coming up with a problem, and I believe the issue is my avr-gcc version - when I run

```
avr-gcc --version
```

I get this:

```
avr-gcc (GCC) 5.4.0
```

But my friend, who is doing a similar project, has avr-gcc version 9.2 on his computer. When we try and compile code on mine, it won't run because the features are too new for my avr-gcc compiler.

Every time I try to simply update using the terminal, it won't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install avr-gcc

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package avr-gcc
```

When I delete avr-gcc and re-download it, it just comes up with 5.4 again. I've looked for a simple download link (like I found this one for Windows https://blog.zakkemble.net/avr-gcc-builds/), but can't find any. Any ideas?

Comment: "*it won't work*"... what do you mean by this? Does anything print to the screen? Are there error messages? If so, provide these in your question post.

Comment: When I type "sudo apt-get install avr-gcc" it Reads package lists, builds dependency tree, reads state information, and then it prints out "E: unable to locate package avr-gcc"

Comment: Can you please provide this log in your question post, as *text*?

Comment: There you go...

Comment: The package is named [gcc-avr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gcc-avr) and according to the right columnt, it actually corresponds to 5.4 version of `gcc-avr`. I don't know how to get the newer version (and I don't know whether the newer version ever exists). Not sure whether the question about *obtaining* a software (event if it is a compiler) is on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can see package labeled Linux on your link, did you try this? Did you try find something on Microchip page? https://www.microchip.com/mplab/avr-support/avr-and-arm-toolchains-c-compilers

Comment: This may be a better fit for superuser.com

Comment: You have to download the code of the compiler and compile it yourself. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) you can find the documentation from `gcc`. If you understand spanish [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/help/instalacion_toolchain.md) there are some notes on how to install all the toolchain in linux (including how to compile avr-gcc)